# Alternative for non existing global dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider

```
def f(x,*args):
    intermediate = computationally_expensive_fct(x)
    return do_stuff(intermediate,*args)
```

**The problem:** For the same *x*, this function might be called thousands of times with different arguments (other than *x*) and each time the function gets called *intermediate* would be computed (Cholesky factorisation, cost O(n^3)). In principle however it is enough if for each *x*, *intermediate* is computed only once for each *x* and then that result would be used again and again by f with different args.

**My idea** To remedy this, I tried to create a global dictionary where the function looks up whether for its parameter *x* the expensive stuff has already been done and stored in the dictionary or whether it has to compute it:

```
if all_intermediates not in globals():
    global all_intermediates = {}

if all_intermediates.has_key(x):
    pass
else:
    global all_intermediates[x] = computationally_expensive_fct(x)
```

It turns out I can't do this because globals() is a dict itself and you can't hash dicts in python. I'm a novice programmer and would be happy if someone could point me towards a pythonic way to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: This is usually called `@memoize`. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize I've not figured out why the answers are reinventing the wheel. I don't see the need to muck about with globals (which is unkind to readers of the code).

Comment: @msw I was reinventing the wheel as I didn't know about `@memoize`. And thanks for pointing to this. May be you should add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

A bit more lightweight than writing a decorator and without accessing globals:

```
def f(x, *args):
    if not hasattr(f, 'all_intermediates'):
        f.all_intermediates = {}
    if x not in f.all_intermediates:
        f.all_intermediates[x] = computationally_expensive_fct(x)
    intermediate = f.all_intermediates[x]
    return do_stuff(intermediate,*args)
```

### Variation

A variation that avoids the `if not hasattr` but needs to set `all_intermediates` as attribute of `f` after it is defined:

```
def f(x, *args):
    if x not in f.all_intermediates:
        f.all_intermediates[x] = computationally_expensive_fct(x)
    intermediate = f.all_intermediates[x]
    return do_stuff(intermediate,*args)
f.all_intermediates = {}
```

This caches `all_intermediates` as an attribute of the function itself.

### Explanation

Functions are objects and can have attributes. Therefore, you can store the dictionary `all_intermediates` as an attribute of the function `f`. This makes the function self contained, meaning you can move it to another module without worrying about module globals. Using the variation shown above, you need move `f.all_intermediates = {}` along with function.

Putting things into `globals()` feels not right. I recommend against doing this.

Comment: Aye, globals are decidedly unpythonic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it why you are trying to use `globals()`. Instead of using `globals()` you can simply keep computed values in your own module level dictionary and have a wrapper function that will look up whether `intermediate` is already calculated or not. Something like this:

```
computed_intermediate = {}

def get_intermediate(x):
    if x not in computed_intermediate:
        computed_intermediate[x] = computationally_expensive_fct(x)

    return computed_intermediate[x]

def f(x,*args):
    intermediate = get_intermediate(x)
    return do_stuff(intermediate,*args)
```

In this way `computationally_expensive_fct(x)` will be calculated only once for each `x`, namely the first time it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

This is often implemented with the `@memoized` decorator on the expensive function.

It is described at https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize and brief enough to duplicate here in case of link rot:

```
import collections
import functools

class memoized(object):
   '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
   If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
   (not reevaluated).
   '''
   def __init__(self, func):
      self.func = func
      self.cache = {}
   def __call__(self, *args):
      if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
         # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
         # better to not cache than blow up.
         return self.func(*args)
      if args in self.cache:
         return self.cache[args]
      else:
         value = self.func(*args)
         self.cache[args] = value
         return value
   def __repr__(self):
      '''Return the function's docstring.'''
      return self.func.__doc__
   def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      '''Support instance methods.'''
      return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)
```

Once the expensive function is memoized, using it is invisible:

```
@memoized
def expensive_function(n):
   # expensive stuff
   return something

p = expensive_function(n)
q = expensive_function(n)
assert p is q
```

Do note that if the result of `expensive_function` is not hashable (lists are a common example) there will not be a performance gain, it will still work, but act as if it isn't memoized.

Comment: Answers that use the `in` operator to see if the answer has already been computed have to take the hashable property into account to work properly.  I mention this because the factorization in the question will likely return a matrix; if the matrix is implemented as a list, it is not memoizable. You can also implement matrices as tuples (immutable lists, mostly) so you might be able to work around this limitation.

Comment: The factorisation will return a big numpy array. Will your solution help under this constraint?